# For which value of $k$ does the matrix $A$ have one real eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> For which value of $k$ does the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}-6&k\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}$$ have one real eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$?

So I understand that if the discriminant is $0$ such that $b^2 - 4ac = 0$ then we have a root of multiplicity of 2 .

So I did $64-48+4k \implies k = -4$ and for some reason it keeps saying I'm incorrect. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the characteristic polynomial of 
$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-6 & k \\
-1 & -2
\end{array}\right]
$
is
$$
\chi_A(t)
=\det(tI-A)
=\det
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
t + 6 & -k \\
1 & t + 2
\end{array}\right]
=t^{2} + 8 \,t + k + 12
$$
This polynomial has a real repeated root if and only if
$$
8^2-4(k+12)=0
$$
Hence $A$ has one real eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity two if and only if $k=4$.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. I was doing $(A - I\lambda)$ instead of $(\lambda I - A)$ thanks @Brian

Comment: @Yusha That shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

we know that the A is $$
    A= \begin{bmatrix}
    -6 & k \\
    -1 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
And due to the $A\vec x = \lambda \vec x$ => $(A-\lambda I)\vec x = \vec 0$,  which the $det(A-\lambda I)=0$

Next, we need to find the matric form of left term and the form of its determinant by elements $$
A- \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}
    -6-\lambda & k \\
    -1 & -2-\lambda \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of the $$det(A-\lambda I)= (-6-\lambda)*(-2-\lambda)-(-1)k = (-6-\lambda)*(-2-\lambda)+k = 0$$
expend the equation of : $$ (-6-\lambda)*(-2-\lambda)+k = 0  $$ $$ (-6)*(-2-\lambda)-\lambda*(-2-\lambda)+k=0 $$ $$12+6\lambda+2\lambda+\lambda^2+k=0$$  $$12+8\lambda+\lambda^2+k=0$$ Using the quadratic formula to find the lambda

So, $a = 1$, $b = 8$, $c = 12+k$,

$b^2-4ac = 8^2-4*1*(12+k) = 64-48-4k = 16-4k$

the square root of the $b^2-4ac$ is $4+2k$ and $4-2k$. Due to the square root of $b^2-4ac$ should be larger or equal to zero, which $16-4k\geq 0$, $k \leq 4$.

Since there is only one real eigenvalue. The square root should be zero which $k$ must be $4$ 
 ($k=4$), and $\lambda = -4$